# Select specific p in current div

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a button with which I want to select only the

in the parent div. I have four of these div with four buttons. I can add an id to each

and make the code four times, but I'd rather find a way to select the p in the div where the button is located.

I tried $('p:'this), $('p:first') and $("p:first-child")

Some select the first child p, but select the other three as well (in other divs). I just want to add a class to the p in the same div as the button.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div><p> Text </p> <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
        $('code to select the <p> in the current div).val();

        $('code to select the <p> in the current div).replaceWith($('.newText').val());
    })
```

newText is an input from a textarea. Tested it with console.log and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the element from the button you clicked on with `$(this)` which is the currently clicked button. Then find the [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) element which is a `<div>` and from there you get the [.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) which is the `<p>`

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    console.log(
        $(this).closest('div').children('p').text()
    );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p>World</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Awesome</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Things</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
```

You can accomplish the exact same thing without jQuery like so

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.btn')].forEach( button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.log(
            event.target.closest('div').querySelector('p').innerHTML
        );
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p>World</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Awesome</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Things</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. .closest is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Roderik your welcome. if your problem is solved please accept. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Siblings function of jQuery to get the "P" tag and replace its value from whatever user has entered in the input field.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('p').text($('.newText').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p> Text </p> 
<button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
<p> Text </p> 
<button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<input class='newText'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).parent().children('p:first-child').text()`

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().children('p:first-child').text()
  $(this).parent().children('p:first-child').text($('.newText').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Placeholder:
<textarea class="newText"></textarea><br>
Items:
<div>
  <p>Hey</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Yo</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Cool</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Man</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Click</button>
</div>
```